# How to scale IDirect3DTexture9 using Direct3D9?

Tags: c++, 2d, directx, scaling

My issue is in commen by ChurchSkiz on this web-page https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/577397-making-a-2d-menu-in-directx/.
Everything is simple, but I cannot understand how to scale that texture.
I want to do it like image for game main menu. How it seems to me, it's only a way which scale any texture to display's resolution of a user (1024x768, 1920x1080 etc).

I also made a non-generic way to scale texture. It depends on centain texture's and display's resolution

```
// The texture are 1024x768 and my display's resolution are 1440x900.
D3DXVECTOR3 center(-200,-50, 0);

sprite_handler->Draw(KidRightTexture, nullptr, &center, nullptr, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 255));
```

Any ideas? Also, is there a better way to draw my texture? For example, maybe without the sprite? I am very new to DirectX.
But everything changes when our display are 1600x1050.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust sprite size, rotattion and world position using [`ID3DXSprite::SetTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174258(v=vs.85).aspx) method. You can use it by building [transformation matrix](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206269(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
::D3DXMATRIX scaling_matrix;
::D3DXMATRIX rotation_matrix;
::D3DXMATRIX move_matrix;
::D3DXMATRIX intermediate_matrix;
::D3DXMATRIX final_matrix;

::D3DXMatrixScaling(&scaling_matrix, scale_x, scale_y, 1.0f);
::D3DXMatrixRotationZ(&rotation_matrix, rotation);
::D3DXMatrixTranslation(&move_matrix, x, y, 1.0f);
::D3DXMatrixMultiply(&intermediate_matrix, &scaling_matrix, &rotation_matrix);
::D3DXMatrixMultiply(&final_matrix, &intermediate_matrix, &move_matrix);

sprite_handler->SetTransform(&final_matrix);
```

But I must mention that the article you posted is outdated. DirectX9 and sprites provided by `D3DXSPRITE` are essentially deprecated.

Comment: I am using Direct3D9 for training purposes. Thank you. How can I use ID3DXSprite::SetTransform, for example?

Comment: I can't say that messing with DX9 sprites is a waste of time but it would be definitely better to switch to DX10-11 and shaders. Implementing custom sprite drawer with DX11 should be a reasonable training task.

Comment: Many D3D9 stuff still using together with D3D11. Is it not prevent my understanding DirectX, basically, if i start from D3D11?

Comment: I would say that starting from Direct3D 11 would provide better understanding of DirectX and graphical programming in general.

Comment: I build simple D3D11 examples, but I never worked with hard D3D11 applications. I'll try.